shopify admin graphql query/filter companies
I have a shopify store with thousands of companies which are assigned to staff members. The idea is to retrieve via admin graphql only the companies assigned to a specific staff member.
Via the admin graphql I am able to retrieve the whole list of companies. However, there is no way to filter the companies by any useful filter:

I cannot search the list for inner nodes (query: "locations.staffMemberAssignments.staffMember.email:xxx@domain.com" gets ignored),
I tried putting  the staff member email in a custom metafield (since they are used to filter the product list) only to discover that query by metafields is not supported in the company object (why? what's the point of having the metafields at this point?),
there are no tags (which I can use to filter customers and companies are a type of customer, so again, I can't understand why a feature is available for an object but not the other).
I even tried to add some notes but apparently the query doesn't even filter the company list by notes!

I've honestly ran out of ideas, I think it's absurd to have a list of thousands of items and no way to filter them. Calling the whole list is not an option, there are too many records. How are people even capable of using this api, am I missing some vital clue?
Is there any way to filter the company list by anything other than the name and the id? How people manage to use this?

According to this community discussion, the desired feature is not currently available within the Spotify API. They offer a workaround and a recommendation to raise the issue on Github.
